# understanding a http request and nested function in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am referencing this code to build a twitch viewer app, which I'm having difficulties in understanding:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let usernames = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"];

  usernames.forEach(function(user) {
    let http = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + user;

    function getAjax(getdata) {
      $.ajax({
        url: http,
        headers: {
          'Client-ID': 'myclientid'
        },
        success: function(data) {
          getdata(data)
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

1. What does 'headers' do exactly? I looked it up on twitch and couldn't find a detailed description. It doesn't look like it gives/adds anything to my http request. Twitch says the header "securely identify my application." but wasn't sure what that mean. I thought if it works similar to an API key it should be included in the request.
2. What does the 'getdata' function in this code do? does it simply store the data i receive from the ajax request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Headers are included in the request. You should be able to see them in the developer tools; this is what it looks like in Firefox

[image: Headers]

2) `getdata` is a callback function that is passed into `getAjax` by consumers, which can then act on the data as necessary, for example...

getAjax(function(data) {
     // do something with data
   })

Note also, you're redeclaring the function in each iteration of the loop, but not actually calling it anywhere. You probably want something more like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let usernames = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"];

  function getAjax(url, getdata) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      headers: {
        'Client-ID': 'myclientid'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        getdata(data)
      }
    });
  }

  usernames.forEach(function(user) {
    let http = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + user;
    getAjax(http, function(data) {
      // do something with data
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: ahh thank you @CaseyWebb! i was aware 'getdata' is a callback function but just didn't understand what it actually does. So i can declare an empty function in a function, store data in it, and i can work with the data later on!